# is this my android code i want to show value toast vale in textview

Tags: android

I want to display the value toast in text view

Code :

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        @SuppressLint({"WrongConstant", "ShowToast"}) Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, " " + String.valueOf((int)(((double)this.intNumber)
                - Math.floor(((double)this.lngDegrees) / (360.0d / ((double)this.intNumber))))) + " ",0);
        toast.setGravity(49,0,0);
        this.blnButtonRotation = true;
        b_start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I would recommend you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to make your question easier to understand and solve for other users. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with Laura. It's hard to guess what you are asking for here.

If you want to show the Toast you should add `.show()` at the end of your toast and change the duration to `Toast.LENGHT_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` instead of "0".
e.g:
`Toast.makeText(this, "yourString", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()`

If you want to access the the value of the String inside the Toast, there is currently no way to do something like that. So the only option is to store it in its own variable:

```
String numberAsString = String.valueOf((int(((double)this.intNumber) - Math.floor(((double)this.lngDegrees) / (360.0d / ((double)this.intNumber)))));  
textView.setText(numberAsString);
//Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, numberAsString, Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
```